# Create static file with logic of angular app during build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have an angular app with extensive logic regarding the generation and interpretation of urls. I want to use this logic to create a set of template url's during the build of the angular and store it a file (e.g. json or xml), so that other systems in our eco-system can use this template to create their own urls. (e.g. for a sitemap.xml file).

We do not have Angular Universal. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: What angular version are you using?

Comment: angular v. 14.3.0

Comment: Was looking for a builder that runs a simple command, but that doesn't seem to exist yet. The point is, in your `angular.json` you can put anything you want under `projects:xxx:architect:chooseacommandname` with a builder you choose. Perhaps you can make use of that to accomplish your goal